# error "File Input" is required value Magento 2

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation, file-upload

I have a customer attribute that is "File Input", type is file and require is true but I do not let it show in customer register. When I try to create an account it displays the error like this:
[image]

How can I ignore this error without changing the require of the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

- If the attribute is required but not provided at customer creation it fail backend validation. Consider a default value.
- To remove frontend validation you have to make sure the attribute is not used in said forms.
- Each Customer Attribute has a value that controls in which forms is used.
- That value is called used_in_forms and it can be altered in an install script with the help of the Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup entity.

E.g. This piece of script makes the Customer Attribute is_authorised be used only in adminhtml_customer form.

```
             /**
             * is_authorised
             */
            $authorisedAttribute = $this->customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_authorised')
                ->addData(
                    [
                        'attribute_set_id'   => $attributeSetId,
                        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                        'used_in_forms'      => ['adminhtml_customer'],
                    ]
                );
            $authorisedAttribute->save();
```

Comment: yes.when i called used_in_forms of "file input".i have :
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "adminhtml_customer"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "customer_account_create"
  [2]=>
  string(21) "customer_account_edit"
  [3]=>
  string(30) "customer_account_edit_frontend"
  [4]=>
  string(21) "is_customer_attribute"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "order_detail"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "show_in_email"
  [7]=>
  string(25) "show_in_email_new_account"
  [8]=>
  string(19) "show_order_frontend"
}

Comment: The attributes I have for displaying at create account have " string(32) "customer_account_create_frontend"